# when two fabricjs rects beside each other

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, fabricjs

Why do i have a horizontal gray line in the middle of two rects ? Even when i set hasBorder to false!

```
  fabric.Rect.prototype.backgroundColor = '#000'
  fabric.Rect.prototype.opacity = 0.7
  fabric.Rect.prototype.selectable = false
  fabric.Rect.prototype.hasBorder = false

  var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c')

  var rect1 = new fabric.Rect({
    left: 0,
    top: 0,
    width: 500,
    height: 100
  })

  var rect2 = new fabric.Rect({
    left: 0,
    top: 100,
    width: 500,
    height: 100
  })

  canvas.add(rect1, rect2)
```

see [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/zgfnj63c/)

Any answer will be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally find the answer to the gray line appearing is because the rect's height is **decimals**, maybe my math calc should be **more precise**! Or to use another way to ***calc with decimals***. 
Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

It is `hasBorders` (instead of hasBorder)

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/m7djt7ty/

Comment: Actually I couldn't see any horizontal gray line in your fiddle btw - I checked in Chrome and IE11

Comment: Thanks! This is my typo in fiddle, but in my project I did use hasBorders, and I finally find the answer to the gray line appearing is because the rect's height is decimals, maybe my math calc should be more precise!
Or to use another way to calc with decimals.
Thanks again!

Comment: No worries! You might want to add that as an answer yourself and accept it. Most folks don't check the comments. Cheers!